# How does an eviction affect a guarantor's credit score?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit-report, guarantor, eviction

If I am the guarantor for someone (say a child, or a younger sibling), and that person got evicted, under what conditions (if any) does this show up on my credit score/report?

Comment: Where are you located geographically? Laws and credit reporting may vary from country to country.

Comment: Located in Texas, USA

Comment: How formal was the eviction? 

Was the lease ended, and the tenants were 'volun-told' to leave? If that's the case that usually won't hit your credit score at all. But if there were actual eviction papers filed, and sheriff's deputies got involved to forcibly remove the guarantee you were supporting from the property, then there is a very slim possibility that would show up on your *legal record* somehow. But that probably wouldn't hit your credit report though--it is expensive to be connected to the credit reporting databases and for most landlords, that's too much trouble.

Comment: The why is important. Were they evicted because they failed to pay rent for a few months?

Comment: How is more important than why. "Why" is almost entirely irrelevant. In order for an event to show up on a credit report, it has to be *reported to the credit reporting bureaus*. [Experian is the only one](http://www.experian.com/rentbureau/rental-payment.html) that reports this. But Experian can only track what gets reported to them, and a landlord needs to be pretty big to justify tracking with them. If it was a formal eviction with court paperwork, then there's a chance it may show up on Teofrostus' legal (not credit) record. But it may not, especially if the tenants were just told to leave

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but it seems that if the eviction was for something other than failure to pay rent, it would be unlikely to show up on the credit record of either the tenants or Teofrostus.

Answer (score 4):

You signed papers saying you would be responsible if the renters didn't pay. If the landlord is looking for the money, expect that they will go after you. If you write them a check for what is owed, it will probably not end up anywhere in your credit report.

But if they have to sue you, or put a lien property you own, or garnish your wages, or have a collection agency contact you, expect that it will be noted in your credit report.

If the renters were evicted or they skipped out on the lease, then the document you, the renters, and the landlord signed will discuss damages. It may also discuss procedures. You should review tenant landlord law for the state where the apartment is located. Many states have a small pamphlet that discusses these issues.